# Fetch optional parameters not working in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am sending optional paramters to a method but they are not received. Using binding.pry I have checked but the link parameter is not received but id parameter is received in the send_email method. It is always returned as nil. Please help find the problem where I am going wrong

```
class EmailsController < MyAccountController
    def send_emails
      @user = current_user
      id = @user.id
      HiringMailer.send_email(id, link: true).deliver_now
    end
end


class HiringMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def send_email(id, joining = false, options={})
    link = options[:link]
    binding.pry_remote
    @user = User.find(id)
    @joining_user = joining
    to = (['abc@yah.com', 'adx@yah.com']).flatten
    mail to: to, subject: "Joining Date"
  end
end
```

Update 1

```
HiringMailer.send_email(id, link: true).deliver_now

def send_email(id, joining = false, , **options)
 binding.pry_remote
end
```

Comment: Could you share your log output when that action is called?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `link: true` argument is getting swallowed up by the `joining` variable.

Let me explain. Here's the method signature:

```
def send_email(id, joining = false, options={})
```

Now, if you call that method with: `send_email(123, link: true)`, then we end up with:

```
id = 123
joining = {link: true}
options = {}
```

To prevent this unwanted affect, you need to explicitly pass all three variables: `send_email(123, false, link: true)`.

...But wait, there's an even better way! *Use keyword arguments instead.* You can define the method like this:

```
def send_email(id, joining: false, **options)
```

And call it exactly like you were doing before:

```
send_email(123, link: true)
```

The only *minor* difference (which is frankly a clear improvement) is that you'll need to invoke the method slightly differently if you want to set `joining = true`:

```
# Before:
send_email(123, true, link: true)

# After:
send_email(123, joining: true, link: true)
```

Comment: HiringMailer.send_email(id, link: true).deliver_now

def send_email(id, joining = false, , **options)
 binding.pry_remote
end

I tried as you suggested, but options is still empty, link is not passed

Comment: That's not what I suggested. Read my answer again :)